# Any risk in creating encrypted ext4 partition to shared drive?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, encryption

I have a dual-boot Win7Pro-ubuntu 17.10 machine (8-core AMD-64 home built) with an extra 600+ GB hard drive that has a an NTFS partition for Windows backups occupying the second half of the drive.  The first half once held an old ubuntu installation but is now unallocated space.  I would like to put an encrypted ext4 data partition (visible only from ubuntu, of course) in that space.  If I do this in the obvious way using the Gnome disk tool, is there any precaution I need to take to avoid damaging the NTFS partition?

Answer (score 0):

All the usual partitioning tools in Ubuntu will preserve existing partitions (including their partition number) by default ensuring that any partition you don't specifically modify should continue to function in other operating systems even when referred to by partition number only.  It would take extra steps to damage or change other partitions.  You just need to ensure that you don't generate a new partition table (which wipes all partitions) and you don't specifically delete a partition you want to keep (or an extended partition containing it).

Even if you do accidentally delete a partition or generate a new partition table, the old partition should still be recoverable by creating a partition with the same partition number and start and end sectors (eg if you write them down first).  Deleting a partition in an Ubuntu based disk partitioning tool won't wipe the data in that partition.